# Can a vector have a wedge product with a scalar? And a geometric product?

Tags: abstract-algebra, clifford-algebras, geometric-algebras

One of the necessary requirements of a vector space is to be endowed with the multiplication by a scalar. I am now interested in other operations, the wedge and the geometric product in geometric algebras.

Can a vector V and a scalar s have a wedge product between each other (V ∧ s)?

If yes: can they have a geometric product between each other as well?

If yes, since the geometric product would be defined (V·s)+(V ∧ s), how exactly are we supposed to handle the inner product component (V·s) given that you can't have an inner product between a vector and a scalar?

Comment: The wedge and geometric products are both equal to scalar multiplication. There is no inner product. That decomposition of the geometric product only works for the vector-vector product specifically.

Comment: do you have some sources about your statement? that would be very helpful for me

Answer (score 0):

If you’ve read any reasonable treatment of geometric algebra, they explain that the algebra contains scalars, vectors, and higher ordered elements, their sums and their products.

The only place where $ab=a\cdot b+a\wedge b$ is relevant is where $a,b$ are vectors. It is not something that holds for every $a,b$ in the algebra.  I think people usually think of it as a derivative identity, not a defining one.

Comment: what would be the correct formula that is always valid?

Comment: @TrentKent6 I'm not sure what you mean. It sounds a bit like you think there's already a scalar product that you can relate to the wedge and geometric product, one that is "correct" and fits into some "correct" formula.  There are many interesting scalar products, and they have interesting relationships with the geometric product, but I can hardly say one is "correct."  [Do a little more research on it here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_algebra#Extensions_of_the_inner_and_exterior_products)

Answer (score 0):

The formula
$$
  ab = a\cdot b + a\wedge b
$$
is true when $a$ and $b$ are vectors, but is usually very wrong in any other case.

The wedge product of a vector and a scalar is the same as the scalar product.

In the Euclidean case, there is a natural inner product on the entire algebra given by
$$
  (X, Y) \mapsto \langle\widetilde XY\rangle
$$
where $X, Y$ are arbitrary multivectors, $\widetilde X$ is the reverse of $X$, and $\langle\cdot\rangle$ is the scalar part. Applying this inner product to a scalar and a vector yields 0; in fact, it will yield zero whenever $X$ and $Y$ have different grades.

Two good references giving an introduction to geometric algebra are *Geometric Algebra for Physicists* by Chris Doran and Anthony Lasenby, and *Clifford Algebras and Spinors* by Pertti Lounesto.